# Countdown timer in tournament registeration app

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, countdowntimer, android-viewholder

I am making a tournament app, where organizer sets up the tournament and a player can register in touurnament. I wanna set countdowntimer in a fragment which has recyclerview. But when i declare CountDownTimer variable and use it in method it gives me error saying:

```
incompatible types: no unique maximal instance exists for type variable T with upper bounds CountDownTimer,View
    countDownTimer = itemView.findViewById(R.id.live_time);
                                          ^
```

where T is a type-variable:
T extends View declared in method findViewById(int)

Please help me!

Recycler viewholder:

```
public class MyViewholder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
TextView TypeTextView,ParticipantsTextView;
ImageView GameImageView;
CountDownTimer countDownTimer;

public MyViewholder(@NonNull View itemView) {
    super(itemView);

    TypeTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.live_tournament_type);
    ParticipantsTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.live_tournament_participants);
    GameImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.live_image_view);
    countDownTimer = itemView.findViewById(R.id.live_time);

}
```

}

Viewholder Layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:padding="8dp">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/live_image_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="250dp"
    android:src="@drawable/live_dota_wall" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/live_tournament_type"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@id/live_image_view"
    android:layout_marginBottom="60dp"
    android:text="Tournament Type: "
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textSize="20sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/live_tournament_participants"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@id/live_image_view"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:text="Tournament \nParticipants: "
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textSize="20sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/live_open_till"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@id/live_image_view"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@id/live_image_view"
    android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
    android:text="Resgisteration \nOpen Till:"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textSize="20sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/live_time"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@id/live_image_view"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@id/live_image_view"
    android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:text="TIME"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textSize="20sp" />
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem in your code is that you are trying to save `TextView` object in a `CountDownTimer` object which is programmatically wrong. This would only be correct if countdown timer was a subclass of TextView .

To use the countdown timer the syntax is very well mentioned in the android documentation
You can check this out

> https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer